# put data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I am using navigation jetpack  in my app.There is an Activity which has a searchview, when person input text in searchview i want to filter recyclerview in fragment, which attach to this activity.

Here is my code snippet :

```
 NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            navController.getGraph())
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);

 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_gallery: navController.popBackStack(R.id.nav_gallery, false);  break;
        case R.id.nav_map: navController.navigate(R.id.nav_map);  break;
        case R.id.nav_favorite: navController.navigate(R.id.nav_favorite);  break;
        case R.id.nav_share: navController.navigate(R.id.nav_share); break;
        case R.id.nav_info: navController.navigate(R.id.infoFragment); break;
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawers();
    return true;
}
```

Here's Searchview implementation in Activity :

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
```

Maybe I must to use navController